90's cop/detective movie
I saw the end of this movie movie (last 10-15 mins) in the early 90s. I don't remember the name of the lead/hero/cop/detective but it seemed like a good movie.
The hero/cop/detective is dejected as his case didn't work out. He is with his partner in an unmarked car, in plainclothes patrolling an area where he sees a person (inferred a burglar) coming out of a high-rise building with some jewellery and using other buildings to come down to the street and do his give-away. The hero/cop/detective sees this but doesn't react. His buddy kinda chides/plays/comments on the detective. Suddenly our hero/cop/detective turns the car and starts chasing the burglar. Now I don't remember whether he gets out of the car and starts running towards the burglar or not, the only thing I remember the 'END' comes while he's chasing him.
Does anybody know the movie I'm talking about?

This might be Fort Apache the Bronx, (1981), with Paul Newman and Ed Asner.  The movie ends with

a purse snatcher who dresses in pull over army surplus clothes as his
  disguise and was targeting elderly welfare recipients on their check
  cashing days is chased by Murphy and Corelli into the ambiguous ending
  that never says if he was successfully captured or not.

The movie is available on Youtube.  They chase him the first time here, and again at the end of the movie here.

Let me see the movie and will let you know, thank you for sharing the answer though.

saw it, it's the one, thank you m8 :)
